# What is the natural maximum number of characters an input field can accept and POST to a PHP script?

Tags: php, forms, input

My questions is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107999/how-many-characters-are-possible-in-an-input-field-in-html), but I **am** interested in posting the data to PHP. I couldn't find anything on Google about this and was wondering if anyone knew the answer?

In essence, how many characters can you put in an input field, submit the form and then successfully receive all of the characters in a PHP script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check answer of this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752768/is-there-a-max-size-to-the-length-of-a-hidden-input-in-html

Comment: Doesn't that other question give a strong hint that the answer depends on the browser and its version (apart of course from server-side restrictions)?

Comment: @Jon I'm guessing server-side restrictions will kick in first, I don't know if any exist though. I couldn't find any by Google, hence the question.

Answer (score 2):

It does depend mainly on the server confinguration. As an example:

```
php_value post_max_size 50M
```

Comment: Thank you. That tells me what I need to know.