# Is there a maximum file count or character limit to file input fields in IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, file-io, input, internet-explorer-11

Just like the questions states, is there a hard limit to either the number of files or characters that can go in a file input in Internet Explorer?

Here's the test code:

```
<html><input id="files" type="file" name="files[]" webkitdirectory directory multiple></html>
```

I've been able to reach a point where files are not accepted with 4,680 files, each 6 characters each for a total of 28,080 characters. Each file is 0 KB in size as well. Additionally, this is being tested on windows with the test directory being C:\tempFolder.

Comment: This is possibly a webserver limitation. There is a Max-Content-Length in web server configurations. The default Max-Content is usually around 4M.

Comment: @Zealander I'm seeing this locally when using an input from a simple html file, there's no webserver behind it.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size is set to 4GB.
 You can refer [What is the maximum file size limitation?](https://github.com/sstur/jquery-file-upload/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not the case either as the files are all 0Kb in size and are not hitting an upload limit.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a duplicate question found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107999/how-many-characters-are-possible-in-an-input-field-in-html) IE8's character limit is around 8,000,000.

Comment: While I appreciate the link, this is clearly not the case because it's failing with significantly less characters than 8M.