# Create File for upload to Spring Controller in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring

I have a really large String that needs to be passed via `input` tag in a html `form` from client to server. Until now I've passed it just as a javascript var like this:

```
document.getElementById("editorText").value = quill.getText();
```

whereas the upload looks like this:

```
<form action="/someEndpoint" method="post">
    <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="margin-top: 15px;" type="submit" th:value="#{mSave}"/>
    <textarea style="visibility:hidden" id="editorText" name="editorText"></textarea>
</form>
```

The problem with this is that the upload does not work this way when the `quill.getText()` gets too large in size. I'd like to handle the upload via multipart file.

So what I need in this case is javascript code that takes the text from `quill.getText()`, creates a file (preferably .xml) and servers this file for upload in the html `form` mentioned above to a controller endpoint looking like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someEndpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFileUpload(final Model model, @RequestParam("editorText") String editorText){

//handling stuff
}
```

I've tried something along the line of `var xml = jQuery.parseXML(quill.getText())` but couldn't quiet get it to work. 
Whats the simplest way to pack the string into a .xml file for upload?

ps: `quill.getText()` is referring to [this](https://quilljs.com/) library

Edit 1: Changed the html `input` to a textfield.

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you have posted, I can see that you are assigning the quill text to a input type text. If you can see the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107999/how-many-characters-are-possible-in-an-input-field-in-html), there is a maximum limit for a input type field.

Whereas, A text area can hold an unlimited number of characters. So, can you try creating a hidden textarea `<textarea style="visibility:hidden" id="quillText"></textarea>` and assign it a value of `quill.getText()`?

It should give you a complete text on the server side.

**EDIT:**

The following code worked for me.

UI:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.1.6/quill.js"></script>

<form action="submitQuill" method="post">
  <!-- Create the editor container -->
  <input type='submit' onclick="javascript:submitForm()"/>
  <div id="editor">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
    <p><br></p>
  </div>
  <textarea style="visibility:hidden" id="editorText" name="editorText"></textarea>

</form>
  <!-- Initialize Quill editor -->
  <script>
    var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
      theme: 'snow'
    });

    function submitForm(){
        var quillText = quill.container.firstChild.innerHTML;
        $("textarea#editorText").val(quillText);
        document.form.submit();
    }

  </script>
```

On server side :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/submitQuill")
    public ModelAndView submitQuill(@RequestParam String editorText){
        System.out.println("Editor Text = "+editorText);
        return new ModelAndView("quill");
    }
```

Output on Console:

```
Editor Text = <p>Hello World!</p><p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p><
p><br></p>
```

Comment: I did not even think about this possibility yet! I tried but could not get it to work, the backend is still throwing the exception that the required parameter is missing.

Comment: Interesting! if you create a textarea like `<textarea style="visibility:hidden" id="quillText" name='quillText'></textarea>` in a form and try to get it as `@RequestParam("quillText") String quillText`, what does it give you?

Comment: I edited the html in my question to the way I changed it according to your hint. Like this I get the following exception in the backend: `org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'editorText' is not present`

Comment: will try to set this 'quill' up in the next week. Never had such a problem while working with online editors. In the mean while, can you perhaps check what is being sent over as a request  in chrome development tools?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the test! This exact setup works for me with smaller text files loaded into the quill editor. Problem occurs only with a really large xml file that has to be handled by the editor. (Notepadd++ Summary: Characters without blanks: 2'421'664
Words: 284'801
Lines: 38'200
Size: 2405 KB

It seems like the problem is on client side since I can't even show the request preview in the dev tools, what to me looks like the request was not built correctly.